# location.reload prevents form submit when POST to iframe (Firefox 37.0.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

**Firefox version is 37.0.2**

I have an MVC application where I submit forms in order to carry out CRUD functions.  I POST to a hidden iframe, then refresh the page after the POST so that the user can see the new data after the database has been updated.  Here is the javascript function that takes care of adding a new user:

```
$('#submitNewUser').click(function () {
                document.getElementById("newUser").submit();
                $('#newUser').remove();
                location.reload();
 }
```

`submitNewUser` is the button for submitting the form (id and name).  `newUser` is the name and id of the modal form that is submitted.  So on click of the `submitNewUser` button, the `newUser` form is submitted, then the `newUser` modal window is removed, then the page is reloaded.

This function works as intended (or at least, as I intended it to) in Chrome and IE.  In Firefox, the page reloads without submitting the form.  There are no errors in the console, it just looks like a page refresh occurs.  When I comment out the line: `location.reload();`, the form submits but I then have to manually refresh the page in order to see the data changes.

I've searched for similar issues but thus far have been unable to fix the problem.  Things I've tried:

- changing the `name` parameter of the iframe to `NAME`
- removing any capital letters from the name and id parameters of the iframe
- using `window.location = window.location` instead of `location.reload()`
- I changed the input type from `button` to `submit` and modified the javascript function to be an `onSubmit` of the form, but the behavior is identical to my original reported issue
- I removed the `target` parameter from the form, and then removed the `location.reload()` line from the javascript.  The behavior is then identical across all browsers: the form gets submitted and the page is redirected to my "Success!" page.  This tells me that there is something going on with the `location.reload()` and how it interacts with the iframe in Firefox.  Here is my iframe code:

  `<iframe id="new_user_hidden_frame" name="new_user_hidden_frame" class="hide"></iframe>`

And here is where I set the target for my POST method:

```
<form id="newUser" method="POST" action='<c:url value="/createUser.htm" />' target="new_user_hidden_frame">
```

**EDIT:**
As per the accepted answer, Firefox was actually the only browser that was technically handing this correctly!  I was refreshing the page before receiving a response, so the behavior was 100% appropriate.  I added the following to my function so the page won't refresh until a response has been received:

```
$.ajax({
     success: function() {
     window.location.reload(true);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code says you are trying to reload page before getting the response, so request is not completed till, for this you have to delay the reload or better way submit form using ajax and reload page in the callback function.

Comment: Aha!  I added some code to the script that checks for success, then refreshes the page and everything is working now.  Thanks!